# pagination in playframework

Tags: pagination, playframework

I want to implement pagination in Play FrameWork , Is there any tutorial or example for this 
I have explore there website and went through the tutorial but not able to implement pagination

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have implemented many pages in `play!` using the [Play pagination module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/paginate-head/home). It's working fine with no issues. I'll give you an idea of what I did, below.

First I declare the `ValuePaginator` that points to a result set (in my case a `MYSQL` query)

```
ValuePaginator vpaginator=query.resultList();
```

Then render the Paginator instance to use it in the view

```
render(vpaginator);
```

In the view, I used the following syntax

```
#{paginate.list items:paginator, as:'r'} 
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>${r[0]}</td>
      <td>${r[1]}</td>
      <td>${r[2]}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
#{/paginate.list}
```

Suppose my SQL query looks like this

```
Select name,id,address from table
```

then in that case `r[0]` will take the value of names, `r[1]` will take the value of id's and `r[2]` will take the value of addresses and render this data in 3 different columns in a table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help, I have the Admin controller  where i have this    public static void userList() {
  
 Iterable<User> users = userService.findAll();
  render(users);                                   and in view  i am using   #{list users, as:'user'}       before my layout  and this at the end of my layout     #{/list}  ,     i've tried to take ur idea but it didnt help , can u guide me how can i change my existing code to urs..  Thanks

Comment: What format is the output of ~userService.findAll();~? Could u paste the list section of ur view here?

Comment: What is the oldest version it supports? I am on 1.2.4, and even though I have added the line to app.conf, my IDE cannot find ModelPaginator or ValuePaginator. I have extracted the module to the modules folder.

Comment: Ok, I built the module and added the jar to build path in eclipse. it works now. Just that resultSet (`java.sql.ResultSet`) cannot be assigned to a ValuePaginator.

Comment: Could you paste the error u get and the line where it occurs in pastebin and then post it here ?

Comment: Its just a single line error I get in the browser. `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet cannot be cast to play.modules.paginate.ValuePaginator`

Comment: Could you paste the code snippet where you query and then assign the result to `ValuePaginator` ?

Answer (score 1):

First solution is to use the [paginate-module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/paginate). Furthermore there was a discussion of different implementations to solve it at [google-group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework) one result of it can find at the [snippet-page](http://www.playframework.org/community/snippets/21).
I hope that one of the solution fits to you.