# paginate-head not showing values in view

Tags: playframework, pagination, playframework-1.x

I compiled and added the paginate-head.jar to my build-path. In my Controller, I get the paginator, and pass it to render.

```
public static void newjoinee() {
    ValuePaginator vp = help.showNewJoineesList();
    render(vp);
}
```

I also added dummy values to the List, and instantiated the Paginator using this list in addition to the List being created as a result of the query.

```
public ValuePaginator showNewJoineesList() {
        List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> bar = new ArrayList<String>();
        bar.add("Ek");
        bar.add("Don");
        bar.add("Teen");
        ValuePaginator vpaginator = new ValuePaginator(bar);


        //Also tried to pass a list obtained as a result of a query.
        //foo = databaseAgent.getloginuserdata();    
        //ValuePaginator vpaginator = new ValuePaginator(foo);
        return vpaginator;
    }
```

In my view, I try to display the list as below, taken from another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671850/pagination-in-playframework).

```
#{paginate.list items:paginator, as:'r'} 
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>${r[0]}</td>
      <td>${r[1]}</td>
      <td>${r[2]}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
#{/paginate.list}
```

I cannot see the list in the view. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first weird thing in your example is that you render a 'vp' variable and use a 'paginator' variable in your view, try to rename your variable to 'paginator' in your controller

Comment: Yes! That was it. Was about to answer my own question, and you beat me to it :)